# How can I sell animated vectors?

Tags: vector, animation, copyright

I am a motion designer and I usually get vector assets from sites like Freepik or Envato Elements... then animate them in order to use them in my motion graphics videos.
I am asking whether it's possible to get those individual elements (let's say a clock or a laptop icon/vector) that I've already animated and sell them ***individually*** or as a ***pack*** or ***any other form*** on sites like Videohive...?

In other words, if I animate those assets (with or without altering them), do I have the right to sell them or even give them for free for people to use in their videos?

Comment: You can not resell an animation using assets from a stock images site. https://www.freepikcompany.com/legal#nav-freepik No. 8 - iv

Comment: Check the licences of the assets. It should tell you what you can and can't do with them.  Also legal questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Wouldn't it feel better to sell something where you *know* that you've made everything yourself? That way you don't have to worry.

Comment: @BillyKerr can you please let me know where I can post for such topics?

Comment: @Wolff the problem is that I am mainly a motion designer and I won't come anywhere close to what those great illustrators are producing

Comment: Try Law Stack Exchange for legal questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to sell: That's not a design problem, it's a marketing problem. You can keep slick watermarked low resolution sample videos visible in marketplaces, YouTube, Facebook etc...

But can you do it legally depends on the licensing of the material you include. Freepik and all other image distributors I know prohibit redistributing their images as is and as a part of other products. There can be some image download sites which have explicit license: "This image is free, use it and redistribute it as you like". I do not know one.

If you haven't got an explicit license which clearly allows redistribution do not redistribute. One possibility is to use images which are made for you for distributing. I guess you have not time to draw them by yourself. A co-operation (have a written and signed agreement) with an artist can be useful.

Warning: there can be criminally acting downloading sites which give images with no license or with a fake license. Downloading pirated stuff from there does not make you free of consequences if you distribute stuff downloaded from them. Before you use an image do image search to see who else has the same image. The real owner may be far less generous than the "download for free" or "buy for $1,-" -site.

Comment: Thank you! I found publicdomainvectors.org which looks pretty legit after a bit of search